# Icons are not displayed in vim-airline and NERDTree

Tags: linux, vim, fonts, vimrc, plugin

I've just installed plugins for my Neovim using vim-plug. 
The plugins are working perfectly,
but it's the icons within them that are haunting me. 
I've provided screenshots of them below.

NERDTree:
[image: NERDTree]

vim-airline:
[image: vim-airline]

They look very weird and it's hard to use. 
Here's what I've tried:

- Installed the plugin https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons
- Installed https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts#font-installation
- Added this `let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1`

I am using Debian Linux AMD64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very common problem with many users after their very first installation of vim-airline plugin. So here are a few steps you have to carry out to see the icons in the vim-airline as well as in the NERDTree plugin.

**Step 1**

Install vim-devicons https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons using any plugin manager (I prefer vim-plug for this. https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) and place it just before the `call plug#end()` command or try to load this plugin at the end of all other plugins(if you are using any other methods to install your plugin) and at the next line paste `set encoding=UTF-8`
example:

```
call plug#begin()
.
.
.
Plug 'https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
set encoding=UTF-8
call plug#end()
```

**Step 2**

Paste the following code after the previous loop

```
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable="+"
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible="~"

" air-line
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

if !exists('g:airline_symbols')
    let g:airline_symbols = {}
endif

" unicode symbols
let g:airline_left_sep = '»'
let g:airline_left_sep = '▶'
let g:airline_right_sep = '«'
let g:airline_right_sep = '◀'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␊'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '␤'
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = '¶'
let g:airline_symbols.branch = '⎇'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'ρ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = 'Þ'
let g:airline_symbols.paste = '∥'
let g:airline_symbols.whitespace = 'Ξ'
" airline symbols                                                                                                                              
let g:airline_left_sep = ''
let g:airline_left_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_sep = ''
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = ''
let g:airline_symbols.branch = ''
let g:airline_symbols.readonly = ''
let g:airline_symbols.linenr = ''

let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFolderNodes = 1
let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFolderNodeDefaultSymbol = ''

let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFileNodesExtensionSymbols = {}
let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFileNodesExtensionSymbols['nerdtree'] = ''
```

**Step 3**

Download any of the font from https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads. I prefer *DejaVuSansMono Nerd Font*.

**Step 4**

`unzip DejaVuSansMono.zip` and do `mv ~/.fonts` and `cd ~/.fonts`

**Step 5**

Finally you have to run `fc-cache -fv` to manually rebuild the font cache. Now reopen the vim or nvim and now you will find that the icons are visible correctly.

Comment: Its been so long and as I never found a fix I used alternatives.... Anyway thanks for your long answer I haven't checked it yet but I hope you are right so I am marking this correct

Comment: Thank you @psychoSherlock for your appreciation. Like you, I also faced the same issue and resolved as per my answer. So thought other developers will also be benifited from my research. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `set guifont=<Your\ Nerd\ Font>` in your `.vimrc`.